# Creating a typescript library that can be used in browser and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, browser, module

I would like to create a library that can be used in both - browser and nodejs. For the sake of the argument let's say this is my library:

```
export default class MyClass {
    public getString(): string {
        return "Message";
    }
}
```

ES2015 modules are not supported by browsers as of now and I don't want to depend on requirejs or any other module loader when in browser - I would like this library to be consumed just by including the generated .js file using the `script` tag. It feels that what I want can be achieved by using internal modules (I don't want to pollute the global namespace).
However when I wrap my code in `namespace`/`module` I am having a hard time to get it compiled to as commonjs module.

What is the proper way of achieving what I want? Or, may be, I am getting completely off the rails here being a typescript and javascript noob?

Comment: Please explain downvotes. It is fine to downvote as long as I know why - I am trying to learn. (also jquery does seem to do what I want as per `https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery` so maybe it's not completely off the rails?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you need is [`UMD`](https://github.com/umdjs/umd). With `tsconfig.json` containing

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "umd"
  },
}
```

generated JavaScript will look like this:

```
(function (factory) {
        if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
            var v = factory(require, exports); if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
        }
        else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
            define(["require", "exports"], factory);
        }
    })(function (require, exports) {
        "use strict";
        var MyClass = (function () {
            function MyClass() {
            }
            MyClass.prototype.getString = function () {
                return "Message";
            };
            return MyClass;
        }());
        exports.__esModule = true;
        exports["default"] = MyClass;
    });
```

It works in node (CommonJS) as well as with browsers (CommonJS, AMD). To allow users of your library to just include it through `script` tag, you need **module bundler** like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org/). Those will produce UMD definition with global export, so default export of main file of your library will be available as some variable in global scope.

Comment: I tried umd but did not postprocess it with webpack/browserify. I will give it a try.

Comment: Looks like with browserify I can create a bundle for all the scripts. I would like to 'bundle' only my library.

Comment: What file do you try to "browserify"? Entry point of your library, right?

Comment: Got it - I did not use the `--standalone` and could not make things work.

Comment: Can you add a clarification on how to use one of these module bundlers in this case?